# Can pyrolytic graphite sheets effectively be used as a thermal gap-fill interface?

Tags: materials, heat-transfer, cooling

Pyrolytic graphite sheets are used as a high-performance thermal interface in applications with high power density because they can have a very high conductivity of 1000+ W/mK, *but only in the horizontal (AB) plane*, so it's typically used to spread heat out from a small source or transport it horizontally.

However, I have an application which requires a rather large thermal gap-fill of ~5mm, and it needs to be both high performance and low weight, so most typical gap pads probably wouldn't be sufficient. I wondered if these graphite sheets could be used in this application by bending them in a U-shape to connect the device and heatsink, but I could not find any examples of them being used in this way.
[image: Diagram of a device being thermally connected to a heat sink using a pad vs. a u-shaped graphite sheet]

According to Panasonic's literature, their pyrolitic graphite sheet (PGS) product is tolerant to bending with a radius of as small as 2mm, as shown in this image:
[image: Panasonic PGS bending test results]

The listed performance of 700-1500 W/mK orders of magnitude greater than a gap-fill pad which is less than 10 W/mK, and 3-5 times greater than bulk aluminum or copper. It also has the benefits of not having to worry about tolerances or compression (PGS is available as self-adhesive sheets), and I guess could even be used across hinged joints.

A naive calculation seemed to suggest that this would be superior to a thermal pad. Using the formula for heat flux
${\displaystyle q=-k\cdot {\frac {T_{2}-T_{1}}{L}}}$ where *k* is the thermal conductivity. In my case, we have:

- The device measures 40x40mm
- A 5mm gap between device and heat sink.
- Temperature difference of 50C
- Suppose that the thermal pad has a conductivity of 5 W/mK.
- The PGS conductivity is 1000 W/mK with a thickness of 0.07mm (from the data sheet).

The heat must travel 5mm through the thermal pad, but must travel about 50mm through the PGS. This is 20mm from the middle to the edge of the device, plus pi*5mm around the 5mm bend, plus another 20mm to the middle of the heatsink.

This gives us:

Thermal pad: ${\displaystyle q=-5\cdot {\frac {50}{0.005}}} = -1.25 W/m^2$

PGS: ${\displaystyle q=-1000\cdot {\frac {50}{0.05}}} = -1,000,000 W/m^2$

Now, we multiply this by the cross-sectional area of each to get the heat transfer rate.

Thermal pad: $1.25 W/m^2 \cdot (0.04 \cdot 0.04) m = 0.002 W$

PGS: $1,000,000 W/m^2 \cdot (0.04 \cdot 0.00007) m = 2.8 W$

Intuitively, I suspect these numbers are not realistic (PGS is probably not a thousand times more effective), but I don't have the knowledge to determine why. How should I go about quantifying the performance of these thermal interfaces?

Comment: No, the thermal conductivity would be terrible: the high specific thermal conductivity is completely outweighed by cross sectional area and the distance that must be traversed through it. If you're in that situation the fundamental design is probably flawed. Why does the heatsink just not extend that distance to begin with?

Comment: In my case, the "heat sink" is just the enclosure. The application has loose tolerances, high vibration, and the enclosure wall is flexible (thin sheet metal), so it is difficult to ensure proper compression of a thermal pad. I don't disagree that "the fundamental design is flawed," but it's what I have to work with.

What would be a good way to assess the thermal performance? I wanted to try simulation, but I doubt most FEA engines would accurately portray transfer through such a thin medium.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the heatsink moves towards the device or the device goes up to meet. The fact that such a huge gap is there indicates a fundamental flaw in the initial design. Thermal gap materials are made to fill the small gaps arising from imperfect smoothness when two surfaces are mated together, not huge gaping distances. Even 0.5mm is too much for a thermal gap material. Transporting heat farther than that requires the use of things like heat pipes or heat spreaders.

Comment: @DKNguyen I was more wondering what approach I could use to predict the (relative) performance of such an interface, rather than trying to solve my particular design problem. I edited my question to add my back-of-napkin attempt at this which didn't seem to give sane results and prompted me to ask.

Comment: Relative effectiveness can be approximated as close to but likely worse than connecting the hottest point on the device to the heat sink with a therm pad of thickness and material properties of your pyrolitic sheet.  Better than nothing, worse than done right ...

Comment: @Abel That's exactly what I did with the example in the question. I didn't think the results were realistic, so I am asking how it can be "done right."